# How to get rid of not secure connection( Not secure https://example) to secure connection.(secure https://example.com

Tags: tomcat8

Hi I'm accessing a site which is on DMZ. I'm getting NOT SECURE https://example.com/. How Can I make it secure only on my machine. I understood that the certificate is not trusted. How can I make my machine trust that site.

I exported certificate from the browser and imported to my trusted root cert and trusted publishers but still I see NOT SECURE warning when I access that website

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You will need to self-sign the certificate or add an exception in your browser. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the reason it is untrusted.  Modern browsers encourage use of Subject Alternate Name entries to identify the identities (DNS domains, IP addresses, etc.) that the certificate should be used for.  If you aren't referencing the site with one of these, you may have trust issues.

Some browsers require you to specify what you trust the certificate for.   If you import the certificate and don't flag it as trusted for web sites, it will not be trusted for web sites.

The simplest approach for a single site is to add an exception for that site.  The dialog to do this should be on the pop-up that says it is untrusted.

There are modern mechanism designed to prevent various security issues such as  man-in-the-middle and certificates from an unauthorized authority.  If they have had them enabled  on the server, the current certificate may ve temporarily (up to a year) untrusted.

Comment: Hello adding to that, I'm using trusted certificate for tomcat web server. when I access it in google chrome I'm seeing not secure warning and in IE certificate error. I checked the certificate issuer which bitdefender which trusted by all. I checked my trusted certicates it is present.

Comment: @Shekar Check that the name you are using to access the server is a Subject Alternate Name for the server.